# What is the optimal strategy in Quantum Tic Tac Toe?

Tags: tic-tac-toe, combinatorial-game-theory

[Quantum Tic Tac Toe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_tic_tac_toe) is a variant of Tic-Tac-Toe with "entangled" states (there are even iPhone and Android apps).

In essence, a classic naught or cross isn't placed until the 'quantum state' of the board is measured and forms a closed loop.

Here the pieces X<sub>3</sub>, X<sub>7</sub> and O<sub>8</sub> are measured when placing the two O<sub>8</sub> pieces are placed and forms a closed loop:

[image]

Upon measurement, the player placing the X marks, picks whether O<sub>8</sub> collapses onto square 3 or square 5. After picking, and resolving entanglement, the board looks like this (O<sub>2</sub> and O<sub>4</sub> collapse in 7, and 8 respectively. X<sub>5</sub> to square 4.)

[image]

Is there a winning strategy for either player? If so, what is it? If not, how can one guarantee a tie?

Comment: @thesunneversets - one of the reasons for posting this was wanting to spread the knowledge - I just found it yesterday and had the same thought as you.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In [Solving Quantum Tic-Tac-Toe](http://rgconferences.com/proceed/acct11/pdf/258.pdf), Ishizeki and Matsuura use a computer to search the game space to find solutions, but don't specifically speak to strategy. However, there are a few strategies we can glean from their results:

1. Go for a half-point victory, not a full point victory. In their search they found the first player, X, cannot guarantee a win by being the only player to get three in a row. But a win can be guaranteed where X and O both have 3 in a row, but X has the lower maximal subscript.
2. As player X, make your first marks split into opposite corners. If X plays perfectly, a half-point win can be guaranteed by playing the first pair of marks, X<sub>1</sub>, in opposite corners.
3. Don't play as O, the second player. Obviously this is not a fair strategy or one you're likely be able to follow in a real game. But since X can guarantee a half-point victory, it follows O can't guarantee a victory.

Since there is a guaranteed path to victory for X, the obvious strategy is to, after playing the first pair in opposite corners, always respond to a move by O by playing such that you are still guaranteed victory (or for O, always play the move that gives you the most options for victory, and hope X makes a mistake). Unfortunately the authors didn't include all of the paths in their search, so it would be necessary to reproduce their results to apply this strategy.

However, I have tried to glean some strategies from the one game they did include in the paper (see Figure 5. I've broken this out into each move in the image below):

1. Avoid entanglements. By not creating a cycle you avoid giving your opponent the advantage of choosing where your marks are fixed. Of course, if you can make a cycle such that either choice is a win for you, like the placement of X<sub>9</sub>, then you should do so. See both the resolution of X<sub>9</sub> and the alternate resolution.
2. Play at least one mark of a pair in an empty square. This increases the chances of having the lowest maximum subscript in a tie breaker, as on each play you add another square where you have the mark with the lowest subscript. X does this up until the last move.
3. Play to increase the number of probable wins. For example on Move 3, after playing X<sub>1</sub> in opposite corners, play one X<sub>3</sub> in the middle and the other in a corner. When one X<sub>1</sub> collapses, the other X<sub>1</sub> that is now fixed will be in line with either X<sub>3</sub>. The same is true for X<sub>3</sub> in relation to X<sub>1</sub>
4. Don't play on your own marks. X never does this until the final move when there is no other option.
5. Don't let your last mark be part of your three in a row. Of course your last move has the highest subscript, and can make you lose the tie-breaker. Making this actually happen may require some additional planning.

[image: Breakdown of Figure 5 game]

Comment: X could force a win on move 7 by resolving O6 the other way and then playing X7 on top of X1, which can only resolve as a diagonal win for X.  This is taking advantage of the general tic-tac-toe rule that the middle square is the most important

Comment: @ChrisDodd that solution gives up X's chance of getting the full point, the solution posted does just as well with the half point forced win but also has a chance to win the full point.